# Ubuntu 12.10 doesn't recognize wireless network it's been connected during installation

Tags: wireless

While installing Ubuntu I connected it to my wi-fi network. But as installation finished I couldn't connect to that same network again because Ubuntu doesn't see it. It does still see other networks but not mine. Changing network name did not help nor did connecting to hidden wireless network. Can anyone help me with this problem? I'm sure I'm not alone having this issue but I couldn't find the answer. 
Thanks in advance!

P.S. I believe re-installation without connecting to wireless would help, but I want to solve it another way.

Comment: What is the output of running the following command in the terminal: lspci

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

1. clicking on the network manager icon
2. Edit connections…
3. Find the wireless connection and delete it.
4. Try connecting again.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it. But it doesn't work. Ubuntu just doesn't see the network. And what is interesting it doesn't see that same network that it's been connected to during the installation process. Strange.